# JavaScript Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a website that navigates through image galleries. When I click the previous or next button I am getting an error code that reads: 'Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference'. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks for any help!

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = showImage(imgName);

function showImage(imgName) 
{
    var largeImg = document.getElementById("large");
    var thePath = "images/";
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;

    largeImg.src = theSource;
    largeImg.alt = imgName;

}

var currentIndex = 0;
function nextGall()
{
    var gallery = new Array();
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall");

    if(currentIndex >= gallery.length)
    {
        currentIndex = gallery.length - 1;
        document.getElementById("next").src = "images/nextEnd.jpg";
    }

    if (currentIndex > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("previous").src = "images/previous.jpg";
    }

    currentIndex +=1;

    for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
    {
        gallery[x].style.display = "none";
    }

    gallery[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    return false;
}

function prevGall()
{

    var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall");
    currentIndex -= 1;

    if(currentIndex <= 0)
    {
        currentIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("previous").src = "images/previousEnd.jpg";
    }

    if(currentIndex < gallery.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("next").src = "images/next.jpg";
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
    {
        gallery[x].style.display = "none";
    }

    gallery[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: If it's happening on one of the `gallery[currentIndex].style.display` lines, it's probably because `currentIndex` is outside the proper range.

Comment: None of your tests for `currentIndex` being outside the range prevent you from getting to those assignment lines.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted the lines of code. Yes, it is gallery[currentIndex].style.display.

Comment: What is the value of `currentIndex` when the error happens? How does it compare to `gallery.length`?

Comment: Correct me where I'm wrong here. currentIndex is = 0 when the page loads with the first image gallery. When I click the 'next' button currentIndex should be = 1(the second position in the 'gallery'[]). This is where I get my error message and the image gallery just disappears from the page. There are 13 positions in the array.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: BTW, why do you do `gallery = new Array()` if you're just going to reassign the variable on the next line? You're never doing anything with the empty array you initialized it to.

Comment: Yes, i've cleaned that up. I was just adding that to see if there was an issue with declaring 'gallery'. Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/collinklopstein/vhuuwLd3/

Comment: `window.onload = showImage(imgName);` is incorrect because the function is invoked immediately. Should be `window.onload = function() { showImage("name_of_some_image"); };`

Comment: Ah, yes. I just commented out that line of code and it is working now!

Comment: You also need to change the fiddle to use one of the No Wrap options, otherwise the buttons can't call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar and cookie monster, here is the solution to my code error. I removed the window.onload command and moved the line of code 'currentIndex =+1;' so the navigation will stop at the last element in the gallery array. Here is the working code:

```
function showImage(imgName) 
{
    var largeImg = document.getElementById("large");
    var thePath = "images/";
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;

    largeImg.src = theSource;
    largeImg.alt = imgName;

}

var currentIndex = 0;
function nextGall()
{
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall");
    currentIndex +=1;

    if(currentIndex >= gallery.length - 1)
    {
        currentIndex = gallery.length -1;
        document.getElementById("next").src = "images/nextEnd.jpg";
    }

    if (currentIndex > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("previous").src = "images/previous.jpg";
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
    {
        gallery[x].style.display = "none";
    }

    gallery[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    return false;
}

function prevGall()
{

    var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall");
    currentIndex -= 1;

    if(currentIndex <= 0)
    {
        currentIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("previous").src = "images/previousEnd.jpg";
    }

    if(currentIndex < gallery.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("next").src = "images/next.jpg";
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
    {
        gallery[x].style.display = "none";
    }

    gallery[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    return false;   
}
```